# Black patch in cycles render

Tags: rendering, objects, light, shadows

I have been trying to remove this black patch for some time now but got no lead. I surfed the internet but couldn't find a thing about this. Please help!

[image: BlackPatch]

Comment: Can you provide your blender file?

Comment: Check for over lapping surfaces and or face normals.